# Right crank (Drive side) on the left?

Tags: crankset

So, I wonder what happen if I replace my left crank with another right crank (either Square tapered or ISIS splined wouldn't matter).

What is the disadvantages apart from:
1) the pedal thread loosening over time (can be fixed using thread locking and hope it works..)

Please list any other problems I might have overlooked

Comment: If you leave the sprockets on it may interfere with the frame, since the right-side crank shaft is often longer than the left.

Comment: Actually the problem on the pedal is opposite - it would tighten.  You pedal pedals off not on.

Comment: You would need two right-pedal spindles, and would have to either rebuild your left pedal onto a right spindle, or have only platform pedals.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you'd have a spider on both sides is one odd and annoying thing. [Sheldon Brown](http://sheldonbrown.com/org/gunnar/) has run the cranks in reverse on regular (non-bmx) bikes [In BMX, there is a reasonable set of options going both ways].

You'd also probably get a strange [Q-factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor_(bicycles)) as well given that the insertion depths are different for the right and left crankarms. This could be compounded if you happen to have a non-symmetrical spindle length bottom bracket.

(It should work in theory - why you'd want to do this in practice unless you were in the odd situation of having two good right crank arms and no good left crank arms is a mystery...)

Comment: I would like to make a motor with freewheel mechanism to drive the left side.

Comment: You should get a bottom bracket, spindle and rear (stoker) crankset for a tandem. They have spiders for chainrings on both sides and correct pedal threads.

Comment: @carel Downside there is the pedals will rotate with the motor, and you can't freewheel or coast.  That would be uncomfortable at higher speeds.